# Meaning of RISC-V ECALL PRIV field

Tags: riscv

What does the PRIV field in the ECALL encoding of RISC-V mean? Is it supposed to encode the mode in which to call the ECALL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of field is ‘funct3’. For many 32-bit instructions it is a second part of opcode. The opcode for ECALL instruction has three parts: ‘SYSTEM’ (1110011), ‘PRIV’ (000) and ‘ECALL’ (000000000000). You cannot change any of them. It would create a different or illegal instruction.